# How do you start a ant build from a maven pom when ant build file is in different directory?

Tags: maven, ant, build, pom.xml

How do you start a ant build from a maven pom when ant build file is in different directory?

I have a ant build file in the following location.

src/main/resources/build/build.xml

I have a pom.xml in the root of the project.

I want to call the ant build from the maven build. Due to the build.xml being a legacy build it only runs from the command line when you are in the src/main/resources/build/ directory. I want a quick way to kick of this ant build as though i am in that directory. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You should use the maven ant plugin.  [Link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to be able to run the ant script from the directory src/main/resources/build/ only from the direcotry where the pom.xml is.

Comment: Yeah, you likely need to move your build.xml up to the directory w/ the pom...or better is to just convert it all to use maven.  You went to maven for a reason, why you still want some part in ant?